# Try Catch array?

Tags: java, arrays, nullpointerexception, try-catch

I get a nullPointerException when I try to use the array. How can I solve it? I have to count the lines in the txt file and use that as my array size.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String accountNum, password, give;  
        int count=0, menuChoice,size=0; 
        String[] validAccounts=null; 

        //gets the data from the file and stores into an array
        try {
            Scanner file= new Scanner (new FileReader("ATMdata.txt"));

            //counts the lines in the text file

            while (file.hasNextLine()) {
                size++;
                String theLine = file.nextLine();
            }

            validAccounts= new String[size];

            for ( int countFile=0; count==size; countFile++) {
                validAccounts[countFile]= file.nextLine();
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error processing file.");
        }
```

Comment: Where are you getting the NullPointerException? Any specific line?

Answer (score 1):

Your last `for` loop has a bad test condition,

```
for ( int countFile=0; count==size; countFile++) {
    validAccounts[countFile]= file.nextLine();
}
```

should be using `countFile` (not `count`) and less than `size` (otherwise your loop body isn't entered)

```
for (int countFile=0; countFile < size; countFile++) {
    validAccounts[countFile]= file.nextLine();
}
```

As is every element in `validAccounts` defaults to `null`.

You also aren't closing your `Scanner` (and you're at the file end). I suggest you use a collection like `List` instead, something like

```
try (Scanner file = new Scanner(new File(
        System.getProperty("user.home"), "ATMdata.txt"))) {
    List<String> validAccounts = new ArrayList<>();
    while (file.hasNextLine()) {
        validAccounts.add(file.nextLine());
    }
    System.out.printf("%d accounts%n", validAccounts.size());
    System.out.println(validAccounts);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: I changed it to that but I keep getting the same error message.

Comment: You changed it to use a `Collection`, and you're still getting a `NullPointerException`? What?

Answer (score 1):

```
// countFile < size, not count == size
for (int countFile=0; countFile < size; countFile++)
{
    validAccounts[countFile]= file.nextLine();
}
```

I believe you need to reset the `Scanner` to the start of the file as well.
In your **while loop**, the `Scanner` has already **moved to the end of the file**.

```
validAccounts= new String[size];
file = new Scanner (new FileReader("ATMdata.txt")); // Add this

// Continue with your for loop
```

Comment: Thanks, Im an idiot for putting "count" instead of "countFile" and reseting the scanner solved the nullException

Comment: Didn't realize that either... my bad

Answer (score 0):

I tested the code below on my computer:

```
Scanner file = new Scanner(new FileReader("H:\\ATMdata.txt.txt"));
e.printStackTrace();
System.out.println("Error processing file.");
```

Does the file exist?